# Service callback for continuous updates

Tags: android

I need to know if there's any method that keeps running as long as a service is active. I'm looking to update some variable continuously from my service (and it's concerned with time, so I can't just use polling mechanism to check for updates). Here's what I plan to do, use a separate thread in my service, and update that variable from that thread. But the problem is, in which method can I update that variable, I don't want to put a while loop in run() method (that'd be plan B), so is there something which can be done regarding this? I have also considered a timer, but as the variable is related with calculation of interval of time, I wouldn't want to execute the same code after every x interval, instead I'd like it to work continuously. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what and when do you want to update?

Comment: Let's say I just want to update the time, and I want to keep it updating continuously, unless the user explicitly stops my service.

Comment: Use a Handler then for example

Comment: I could do it the other way, using a separate thread inside the service, and running it until the user stops my app explicitly. Hence, I had to use while loop to test the condition of a variable which I set to false, when user stops my app. A question though, isn't there anything through which I can avoid this while loop, as I tried handler too, but I had to use while loop in that too. Thanks anyways for your reply.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean at all, sorry

Comment: That's all right,  I can't post code else it would have been much clear. Anyways I solved the problem. Thanks